renovate rebase and merge automatically approved PRs
My team and I need want renovate to be able to automatically rebase et merge PRs, once it has been approved by us.
I found some documentation on how to automatically approve PRs and merge but I cannot find something about rebasing and merging only the ones that are approved, without rebasing the ones that are not.
Any help ?
Thanks

Not helping but is that really an issue if Renovate rebase too early or too much?

it costs CI time and we are supposed to be careful about the bill in the end of the month :/

Did you think about running renovate less often?
Also you might want to have another look at the rebase config: https://docs.renovatebot.com/updating-rebasing/ and ask the renovate team directly about possible solutions on GitHub: https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions
